# PHP's DOMXpath fails to return the complete set of children nodes

Tags: php, xpath

I have 9 table rows but only three get returned when I query the top level node with DOMXpath.

```
<table class="something">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">One</td>
            <td>111111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Two</td>
            <td>1454</td>
        </tr>    
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Three</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Four</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Five</td>
            <td>45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Six</td>
            <td>45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Seven</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Eight</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Nine</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I use DOMDocument to load the HTML.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($htmlData);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$tableRows = $xpath->query('//table[@class="something"]//tr');
```

Unfortunately, the complete set of table rows are not being returned -- only the first three. I'm guess that the empty element `<td></td>` is somehow throwing off the xpath parser. Is there a solution to this?

EDIT:

I'm trying another approach without using DOMXpath.

```
    $request = drupal_http_request($url);

    $data = $request->data;

    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    @$doc->loadHTML($data);
    $tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
    $rows = $tables->item(2)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    $output = '';
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        foreach($cols as $col){
            $output .= $col->nodeValue . '<br/>';
        }
    }
    return $output;
```

Both approaches output this HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    One<br>111111<br>Two<br>1454<br>Three<br><br>
</div>
```

In the first example $tableRows->length is 3 which is consistent with the output but not the markup which has 9 rows.

Comment: Not sure if this is a transcription error or code typo, but table class above is somethiing and not something.  Secondly, I get 8 //tr results with that query just fine?

Comment: Your XPath is totally fine. What's the PHP code coming afterwards? Probably the problem is in there.

Comment: It could be that I'm scraping a webpage that has bad markup and is throwing off DOMDocument

Comment: The complete page would be helpful. A tiny possibility is that your display routine is throwing you off? Try iterating through the $tableRows: foreach( $tableRows as $row ) { echo "{$row->nodeName}\n"; }

Comment: seems to be working after correcting "somethiing" to "something": http://codepad.viper-7.com/vCiisu

Answer (score 0):

I'm scraping a webpage that has invalid, corrupted, dirty HTML. DOMDocument likes clean and organized (I guess). Instead I'm using the [simple_html_dom.php](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) script to parse the HTML and it works fine.